# Insert $_POST associative array into database PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

How would I go by inserting a assoc array into a MySQL database.

When I `print_r($_POST)`, I get this:

```
Array
(
    [first_name] => Array
        (
            [0] => James
            [1] => Will
            [2] => Jackie
        )

    [last_name] => Array
        (
            [0] => Bond
            [1] => Smith
            [2] => Chan
        )
)
```

What I have in mind is something like this.

```
INSERT INTO actors(first_name, last_name) VALUES ('val1','val2'), ('val1','val2'), ('val1', ....
```

or something like this.

```
$sql="INSERT INTO actors(first_name, last_name)VALUES(:first_name,:last_name)";
$stmt=$db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue(':first_name', $_POST['first_name']);//Here I get a "Array to string conversion" error 
$stmt->bindValue(':last_name', $_POST['last_name']);// Here I get a "Array to string conversion" error

foreach($_POST as $row){
$stmt->execute($row);//Here I get a "PDOStatement::execute() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given" error
}
```

I know there are many questions similar to this, I have viewed them all and tried the ones I could understand.

Here is the html form I'm trying to use to post to the database:

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="first_name[]" placeholder="First Name"/>
    <input type="text" name="last_name[]" placeholder="Last Name"/>
    <input type="text" name="first_name[]" placeholder="First Name"/>
    <input type="text" name="last_name[]" placeholder="Last Name"/>
    <input type="text" name="first_name[]" placeholder="First Name"/>
    <input type="text" name="last_name[]" placeholder="Last Name"/>
    <input type="submit" name="add_actor" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Hi, why don't u just loop ur values `$stmt->bindValue(':first_name', $_POST['first_name']);$stmt->bindValue(':last_name', $_POST['last_name']);` .. Doesn't it work ?

Comment: I get a "Array to string conversion" error with and without loop

Comment: even in the loop ?? Once try like this.. 
`foreach($_POST['first_name'] as $key=>$value){$stmt->bindValue(':first_name', $value);$stmt->bindValue(':last_name', $_POST['last_name'][$key]);}`

Comment: We getting close :D.

Comment: But now I get `:first_name` and not the value

Comment: this wouldn't be a problem if you weren't mindlessly copy and pasting without an understanding of the code.

Comment: @user3284463 Check out my answer

Comment: Sorry was a typo in sql.

Comment: @phpfresher thanks! But what if I had a third, first_name, middle_name, last_name

Comment: @user3284463 How do you insert values into database right now?

Comment: @BasheerAhmed I'm trying to keep using prepared statement and if things don't workout I will use a simple straight forward sql. So, at the moment I'm trying phpfreshers method

Comment: Hi, if you have like `first_name`, `middle_name`, `last_name`, then also the same procedure.. `$stmt->bindValue(':middle_name', $_POST['middle_name'][$key]);`, just the names changes... procedure will be same..

Comment: Thanks!!! Been stuck at this for many days! Finally got it to work. Thanks alot @phpfresher and everyone

Comment: Looping a query is not a feasible solution instead you can try [this](https://eval.in/468672)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like

```
foreach($_POST["first_name"] as $k=>$v){

  $f_name = $v;
  $l_name = $_POST["last_name"][$k];

  $sql="INSERT INTO actors(first_name, last_name)VALUES($f_name, $l_name)";
  // James Bond
}
```

I would do some sort of validation however to count the values being posted.

Comment: Looping a query is not a feasible solution

Answer (score 1):

This is what you want!

```
$sql="INSERT INTO actors(first_name, last_name)VALUES";

do{
    $actors_name = array_shift($_POST['first_name']);
    $actors_surname = array_shift($_POST['last_name']);
    if($actors_name || $actors_surname)
        $sql.="(".mysqli_real_escape_string($actors_name).",".
                mysqli_real_escape_string($actors_surname)."),";
}
while($actors_name || $actors_surname);

//CUT LAST COMMA FOR A CORRECT QUERY
$sql = substr($sql, 0, -1);
```

Comment: mh i probably misunderstood

Comment: using json_encode, I get a value like `["james"]` in my table

Answer (score 0):

I'll change how you pass data, setting index before parameter name

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="[0][first_name]" placeholder="First Name"/>
    <input type="text" name="[0][last_name]" placeholder="Last Name"/>
    <input type="text" name="[1][first_name]" placeholder="First Name"/>
    <input type="text" name="[1][last_name]" placeholder="Last Name"/>
    <input type="text" name="[2][first_name]" placeholder="First Name"/>
    <input type="text" name="[2][last_name]" placeholder="Last Name"/>
    <input type="submit" name="add_actor" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Now you can correctly execute statement:

```
foreach($_POST as $row){
$stmt->execute($row);//Here I get a "PDOStatement::execute() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given" error
}
```

Comment: this would work ...but not for those fields that are added dynamically with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your first name and last name values are on the same indexes but on different arrays so you can concat them using array_map function something like

```
$array1 = array('first' => array('basheer','salman'));
$array2= array('lastname' => array('kahn','ali'));

$result_array = array();

array_map('concate', $array1, array_values($array2));
function concate($array1, $array2){
    global $result_array;
    foreach($array1 as $key => $val) {
        $result_array[] = '(' . $val . ',' . $array2[$key] . ')';
    }
}
print_r(implode(',',$result_array));//(basheer,kahn),(salman,ali)
```

And your sql query will look like something

```
INSERT INTO actors(first_name, last_name) VALUES implode(',', $result_array)
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use a for loop to iterate the the arrays in unison. pretty simple stuff here. `$i` is an integer that increments, so its always selecting the next incremental row. 1 problem is that the indexes will be out of order on one side if any of the fields were left blank, so this design is flawed from the jump.

```
$sql="INSERT INTO actors(first_name, last_name)VALUES(:first_name,:last_name)";

$num_rows = count($_POST['first_name']) + count($post['last_name']) / 2;

for($i=0;$i<$num_rows;$i++)
{   
    $stmt=$db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindValue(':first_name', $_POST['first_name'][$i]);
    $stmt->bindValue(':last_name', $_POST['last_name'][$i]);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Comment: is this tested? I get errors `Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined`.  if try `$stmt->execute($sql);` then I get errors saying  `Undefined offset: 1` and `PDOStatement::execute() expects parameter 1 to be array`